# PHP: Get image type from base64 string

Tags: php, image, base64

How do I get the image type from a base64 string?  I read another post similar to this but it doesn't give the image type, jpeg, png, etc.  Below is my current code.

```
$type = finfo_buffer(finfo_open(), base64_decode($b64Img), FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
print($type);
//prints "application/octet-stream"
```

Comment: where is `$b64Img` assigned? how is it assigned?

Comment: $b64Img is assigned earlier in the code.  It's just a base64 string representation of an image

Comment: What is the value of `$b64Img`?

Comment: What kind of image? `$b64Img = base64_encode(file_get_contents('scarlett_johansson.jpg'));`? What's the source of the base64 data?

Comment: $b64Img is sent from javascript.  The user selects an image from a file input, it's converted to a base64 string, then sent to the server.  After its been sent, I want to see whats the type of image I'm going to be dealing with.

Comment: So you should decode the first few characters and test them. It will be the magic of the file. Just test them as my answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

This code should work, give it a try:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
echo $finfo->buffer(base64_decode($b64Img)) . "\n";
```

Comment: This prints out "application/octet-stream; charset=binary"
I'm looking to see if the file is jpg, png, gif.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Then you've just got some binary chunk. `finfo` does not find any image type on the file buffer you obtain information from.

Comment: Is there a way to see if its a jpeg or not?

Comment: Sure, make a hexdump of the data you get and inspect it comparing against the JPEG file format specification. The first bytes should be enough to find out.

Comment: Care to share what your actual issue was?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of FILEINFO_MIME you can also use FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE available since PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to decode the base64 data and then read the magic of it:

```
// read first 12 characters out of the base64 stream then decode
// to 9 characters. (9 should be sufficient for a magic)
$magic = base64_decode(substr($b64Img, 0, 12));

// determine file type
if (substr($magic, 0, 1) == 0xff &&
    substr($magic, 1, 1) == 0xd8)
{
    // jpg
}
else if (substr($magic, 0, 1) == 0x89 &&
         substr($magic, 1, 5) == "PNG\r\n" &&
         substr($magic, 6, 1) == 0x1a &&
         substr($magic, 7, 1) == "\r")
{
    // png
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the base64 text of your image, you just need to analyze the first section of it to determine the file type.  All base64 strings begin with something like this:

`"data:image/(png|jpg|gif);base64,iVBORw0KG..."`

You just have to look at the part between the `image/` and the `;` and it will tell you the format.